# what does Complete redesign of "property access" contracts mean in hibernate migration guide

Tags: java, hibernate

There is a sentence in the hibernate 5.0 migration guide which says `Complete redesign of "property access" contracts` [Link](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.0/migration-guide.adoc#misc). Unfortunately, this does not provide any additional information.
On checking over the internet all I could find was the different ways of accessing in JPA (Field-based and property-based). Does the sentence mean the hibernate code for accessing these has been changed?